# How to create a recursive backwards toString()

Tags: java, recursion

I created a toString recursive function and when i change first to last in the function to make it print backwards it doesn't output anything. It looks like it just keeps calling the function over and over.

```
public String recursiveBackwardsString() {
    if (this.isEmptyList()) {
        return ("");
    } else {
        DoubleLinkedList < T > otherList = new DoubleLinkedList < T > ();
        otherList.copy(this);
        otherList.deleteNode(otherList.last.info);
        return ("" + this.last.info + otherList.recursiveBackwardsString());
    }
}
```

and my toString that works is:

```
public String recursiveToString() {
    if (this.isEmptyList()) {
        return ("");
    } else {
        DoubleLinkedList < T > otherList = new DoubleLinkedList < T > ();
        otherList.copy(this);
        otherList.deleteNode(otherList.first.info);
        return ("" + this.first.info + otherList.recursiveToString());
    }
}
```

Could anyone tell me the problem with the backwardsToString??

```
public void deleteNode(T deleteItem){
DoubleLinkedListNode<T> current= new DoubleLinkedListNode<T>();
current=first;

if(this.isEmptyList()){
System.out.println("List is empty"); 
return;
}
else if(first.info.equals(deleteItem)){
 if(count>1){
   first=first.next;
   first.back=null;
   count=count-1;
   return;
 }

 else{
 first=null;
 last=first;
 count=0;
 return;
 }}
else{

 current=first.next;
 while(current!= null){
   if(current.info==deleteItem){
     current.back.next=current.next;
     current.next.back=current.back;
     count=count-1;
     return;
   }

 }}

System.out.print("Item not in the list");
return;
}
```

Comment: is `deleteNode` actually deleting a `node`?

Comment: deleteNode is a function

Comment: I know it is a method...Is it actually deleting anything in your `recursiveBackwardsString()` `method`? Did you try debugging?

Comment: Could you show your `deleteNode` implementation?

Comment: In your `else` why is `if(current.info==deleteItem){` not `if(current.info.equals(deleteItem)){`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this:

```
else{

    current=first.next;
    while(current!= null){
        if(current.info==deleteItem){
            current.back.next=current.next;
            current.next.back=current.back;
            count=count-1;
            return;
        }

    }}
```

to:

```
else{

    current=first.next;
    while(current!= null){
        if(current.info.equals(deleteItem)){
            current.back.next=current.next;
            current.next.back=current.back;
            count=count-1;
            return;
        }

    }}
```

Notice the `==` to `.equals()`.